# Wijmo 5 with Angular System.register is not supported by webpack

Tags: angular, angular-cli, wijmo, wijgrid

I tried to use FlexGrid of Wijmo modules next when i serve my project 
I got this Error :
(I am using AngularCLI)

```
WARNING in ./~/wijmo/wijmo.angular2.core.js
System.register is not supported by webpack.
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 12:0-57
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

despite the import was working in app.module.ts

```
import { WjCoreModule } from 'wijmo/wijmo.angular2.core';
import { WjGridModule } from 'wijmo/wijmo.angular2.grid';

 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    WjCoreModule,
    WjGridModule
  ],
```

Thanks TEAM ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally if found solution, apparently i got the wrong npm package, 
then there are three types of JavaScript module systems of npm packages

```
( CommonJS - AMD - System )
the right package that works with AngularCLI is AMD module system
```

C1Wijmo-Enterprise-Eval-AMD-5.20172.328

[Wijmo 5 reply](http://wijmo.com/topic/wijmo-5-with-angular-system-register-is-not-supported-by-webpack/#post-108071)

## GridWijmo5

How to install Wijimo Grid :

Take the last version of Wijmo from this url :

> http://prerelease.componentone.com/wijmo5/npm-images

**Required for AngularCLI**: AMD version.
So you have two choices :

***First 1 :***

Add this dependency in package.json file :
section : "dependencies"

```
"wijmo": "http://prerelease.componentone.com/wijmo5/npm-images/C1Wijmo-Enterprise-Eval-AMD-5.20172.328.tgz",
```

and Redo: npm install

it's same to do:

```
npm --save install http://prerelease.componentone.com/wijmo5/npm-images/C1Wijmo-Enterprise-Eval-AMD-5.20172.328.tgz
```

**Second 2:**

because yarn is hanging this package name, we ll add it manually in our node_modules/

```
wget -P node_modules/wijmo/ http://prerelease.componentone.com/wijmo5/npm-images/C1Wijmo-Enterprise-Eval-AMD-5.20172.328.tgz
```

extract the download file.

and make dependencies to this folder

```
"wijmo": "file:node_modules/wijmo",
```

### Styles Grid

- Fetch the style file into src/assets/css/ folder

> mkdir src/assets/css/ && curl -O 
>   http://cdn.wijmo.com/5.20172.334/styles/wijmo.min.css >
>   src/assets/css/wijmo.min.css
>
> Add Wijmo.min.css file in the Angular-cli.json file

```
"styles": [
            "styles.css",
            "assets/css/wijmo.min.css"
        ],
```

Import the WjGridModule in your app.module.ts

you should to check if the import Module is good.

import { WjGridModule } from 'wijmo/package/wijmo.angular2.grid';
import { WjCoreModule } from 'wijmo/package/wijmo.angular2.core';

after Continue to develop ^^^

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using `wijmo5` with `angular-cli`.

- Download the zip from the website and extract this folder `NpmImages\wijmo-amd-min`.
- Inside `package.json` add `"wijmo": "./vendor/wijmo-334/wijmo-amd-min"` (link to where you extract the folder).
- `npm install`

Then it works nicely!

Comment: Thank Mr, i think that it s better if you put Wijmo folder inside node_modules

Comment: yes that's what `npm install` do, it copy the folder inside `node_modules`. I prefer this way because a common way to work is to ignore `node_modules` folder with versionning system like git.